# Placement/Alignment issue with html form?

Tags: html

I have a form which looks like this

```
<form method=post action=index.php>

<table>
<tr>
        <td>Character Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="cname" name="cname"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>Race</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="race" name="race"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>Side</td>
        <td>  <input type="radio" name="side" value="1"> Good</input>
                  <input type="radio" name="side" value="2"> Bad</input>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <input id="step" name="step" type="hidden" value="5"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

All of the fileds inside the form are in a table. The problem I am facing is that, the submit button, rather than coming at the bottom, is coming at the top.[image]

Could somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Inputs are self-closing so there is no `</input>` and your last table row is missing opening and closing `<td>` elements

Comment: For radio buttons, use `<label for="my-radio"><input type="radio" id="my-radio"> Your text here</label>` to ensure the element is checked when the text is clicked.

Comment: Also, this code would benefit from proper indenting. Ensure each `<td>` is properly indented and you would clearly see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<table>
    <tr>
            <td>Character Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="cname" name="cname"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Race</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="race" name="race" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Side</td>
            <td>  
                <input type="radio" name="side" value="1" /> Good
                <input type="radio" name="side" value="2" /> Bad
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="step" name="step" type="hidden" value="5" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```